# Error: libc++abi.dylib`vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm building a game with cocos2d-x for iOS 6/7 (Using Xcode 5 and iOS SDK 7.0), and started introducing some patterns that exploit inheritance, and I ran into this exception.

```
libc++abi.dylib`vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info:
0x284a540:  addb   %al, (%eax)
0x284a542:  addb   %al, (%eax)
0x284a544:  jo     0x284a4eb                 ; vtable for __cxxabiv1::__libcxxabi::__void + 91
0x284a546:  testb  (%edx), %al
0x284a548:  lesl   2(%edx,%eax,4), %ebx
0x284a54c:  movl   $2046984796, %edx
0x284a551:  popl   %esp
```

The code looks this:

```
     for (auto enemyItr = EnemyQueue::getEnemyContainer().begin(); enemyItr != EnemyQueue::getEnemyContainer().end(); ++enemyItr)
            {
                EnemyCharacter *enemyCharacter = dynamic_cast<EnemyCharacter*>(*enemyItr);
                CCSprite *enemy = enemyCharacter->getCharacterSprite(); // inhertiance introduced to EnemyCharacter class

                CCRect enemyMeleeRect = enemy->boundingBox(); //-> exception
}
```

I thought this is a linker error, and tried including libstdc++ "Link Binary with Libraries". I also tried including "-lstdc++" in Other Linker flags as well, but the exception persists.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Are you linking the libc++abi.dylib library?

Comment: Almost looks like you branched into a vtbl, which is a bad idea.  (vtbls are just tables of pointers.)

Comment: I think the key here is `enemyCharacter->getCharacterSprite()`. Determine the specific `EnemyCharacter` subclass which causes the exception and double check it's implementation of `EnemyCharacter:: getCharacterSprite()`

Comment: Tried including libc++abi, didn't make a difference. Well, that subclass does nothing with that method. That's just a getter method. This has something to do with using the map, and casting it back. Because at the point at which the object is inserted into the map, it's all good. At this point, it seems as if it retrieved a stripped down object. I'm unsure as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason was due to the use of C style callbacks in the cocos2d x framework. I had made these functions virtual, and hoping to override them in derived classes. But, that causes this exception. I guess I have to find a workaround or just forget about using OOP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, adding `libstdc++.dylib` from `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` resolved the error. Hope it will help others coming to this question.